# Laravel Blade not showing data from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show data in tabular form in Laravel Blade View. Now, data is not showing up in blade, but when I check in controller using `print_r` it shows up Following is the code for Controller:-

```
public function index(){

    $pickup = PickupLocation::select('*')
                    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();

    $page = 'pickup_locations';
    return view('backEnd.pickupManagement.index',compact('page'));
}
```

Following is the code in `web.php`:-

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'pickup-locations','backEnd\pickupManagement\PickupController@index');
```

And following is the code I am using `View`:-

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th width="13%">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @if(!empty($pickup))
                                    @foreach($pickup as $key=>$value)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ ucfirst($value['name']) }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ucfirst($value['contact_no']) }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $value['location'] }}</td>

                                            <td>
 <a href="{{ url('/admin/pickup-location/edit/'.$value['id']) }}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
 <a href="{{ url('/admin/pickup-location/delete/'.$value['id']) }}" title="Delete" class="del_btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach    
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `@if(!empty($pickup))` ... `$pickup` is not set from your controller, it's `$page` ... and it's just a string `'pickup_locations'`, you might want `return view('backEnd.pickupManagement.index',compact('pickup'));`

Comment: You are not returning `$pickup` variable, just `$page` add pickup to compact `return view('backEnd.pickupManagement.index',compact('page', 'pickup));`

Answer (score 0):

add  $pickup variable as second argument in your compact method.
Try like this

```
return view('backEnd.pickupManagement.index',compact('page', 'pickup')); }
```

Happy codding